# Орфография сочетания «трудо- и финансово затратный»

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Сомневаюсь в написании словосочетания "трудо- и финансово затратный".

*... менее привлекательный вариант, так как более трудо- и финансово затратный.*
Можно ли так писать? Если нет, то как будет правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно придется остановиться именно на таком написании:

***... менее привлекательный вариант, так как более трудо- и финансово затратный.***

**Пояснение**

1. По правилам регламентируется другой вариант: кукурузо- и силосоуборочные комбайны, но при этом у нас есть слова со слитным написанием: кукурузоуборочный и силосоуборочный.

Правило Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49
Пункт 16. При употреблении ряда сложных прилагательных возможно использование «висячего» дефиса: семнадцати- и восемнадцатилетние юноши и девушки; кукурузо-, картофеле-, льнохлопко- и силосоуборочные комбайны.

2. У нас сочетаемые слова имеют **разную форму написания:** *трудозатратный* и *финансово затратный*, поэтому у Розенталя такой вариант не разбирается.

Но по логике висячий дефис должен соответствовать слитному написанию: трудозатратный, а в целом такая запись **смотрится вполне корректно** (другой просто не поберешь, так что выбирать не из чего).

Вследствие изложенных причин желательно использовать именно этот вариант.

**Приложение:**

Вопрос № 239130 . Как пишется слово "финансово затратный" (раздельно или через дефис)?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Корректно раздельное написание.

Орфографический словарь: трудозатратный